# Java - assigning two expressions to a single variable simultaneously

Tags: java

I've just finished my first year of Java and I've been looking at the JDK source code as an exercise.

I came across something I've never encountered before where there were two assignments to the same variable in the same statement.

e.g.

*variable* = *expression* = *expression*;

What exactly is going on here? Is this a fairly common thing? What is the purpose of a double assignment?

Thanks a lot
-Mike

Comment: If you have posted the example, it would be easier to answer...

Comment: is that even possible? variable = otherVariable = expression would make sense

Comment: I thought this was a mutex question after seeing the title :]

Comment: @Petar - I was thinking more x = y = 3;

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I see, I deleted my comment:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
variable1 = variable2 = expression;
```

Can be written as

```
variable2 = expression;
variable1 = variable2;
```

This is because equal signs are evaluated from right to left after everything else is evaluated (basically the lowest operation in order of operation).

This is generally seen as tacky, and I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you've meant

```
variable1 = variable2 = expression;
```

In this case expression will just be assigned to both variables.

This could be written as

```
variable1 = expression;
variable2 = expression;
```

So you can use style described in your question just to make code shorter and more elegant.

Comment: It is *not* more elegant. Making code shorter isn't always a Good Thing.

Comment: I think in the original the expression will be evaluated only once.  In your rewrite it will be evaluated twice.

Comment: Qwerky, I agree with you, that Making code shorter isn't always a Good Thing. But this case, as for me, is elegant. Just as for me :)

Comment: What's good for you is less important than what's good for the poor fellow maintaining the code in 5 years time.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot assign two expressions to one variable simultaneously.**

```
variable = 3 = 2;
```

This code will not compile.  Maybe you are seeing something like this:

```
variable = x = 3;
```

In this case, this is actually *variable = variable = expression* and is assigning the same expression to two variables.  This is possible because the value of an assignment operation is the value being assigned.  So in this specific case, the `x = 3` is executed first and has a value of 3, which is then assigned to `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

It's becouse in Java assignements have a return (the result of the left expresion)!

Its very usefull to use in loops like when you read files in a byte array: you can track the num of bytes readed and know when the file is over:

```
InputStream is=......
byte[] b=new byte[1024];
int read;
for(;read=is.read(b)>0;){
    //do stuff knowing how many bytes hav been readed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is legal but generally discouraged. Even's [Sun's standard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-142311.html#430)s recommend against it.

Edit:
Like other people, I'm assuming you mean `variable1 = variable2 = expression;`

Comment: Java standards say about coulpe independent statements on one like. In our case its a bit different.